# How to create this type of gradient as in ZOMATO app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

[image]

Please have a look at the provided image

Comment: ask your designer to create this type of image and then you can use this image as a background.

Comment: That basically is not a gradient. It a view with transparency. It looks like a gradient because of the background food